# Rails join query with array of children : get corresponding parents with "ALL" children, not "ANY"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, activerecord

I have this ActiveRecord query that gives me posts that contain any of the tags listed in tag_ids :

```
Post.joins(:tags).where(tags: { id: tag_ids })
```

Is there something I can to become exclusive instead of inclusive ?
I want only posts that match all tags in tag_ids.

I'm using Postgres, and looking maybe at doing it through `arel` ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```rb
Post.joins(:tags).where(tags: { id: tag_ids}).group(:id).having("COUNT(DISTINCT tags.id) = #{tag_ids.count}")
```

Comment: Took me a while to make sure how this would fit all use cases, but it looks like it. Thanks a lot !